# Yandex Translate Api android

Tags: android, api, translate, yandex

I added library [enter link description here](https://github.com/vbauer/yandex-translate-api) but after launching
the app I take an error like that *Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: unsupported class file version 52.0* Sorry for my English. Please, help me

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.macbookairmd760.zaebalas"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    javaCompileOptions{
        annotationProcessorOptions{
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }

}
buildscript {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {

    }
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    incremental false
}
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.vbauer:yandex-translate-api:1.2.5'
```

}

This is an error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:  at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:176)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder.processOutputs(DexArchiveBuilder.java:95)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder.convert(DexArchiveBuilder.java:78)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.lambda$cacheMissAction$0(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:233)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$createFile$1(FileCache.java:262)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$null$5(FileCache.java:423)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.doInterProcessLocked(FileCache.java:668)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.doLocked(FileCache.java:620)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$queryCacheEntry$6(FileCache.java:402)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.doInterProcessLocked(FileCache.java:668)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.doLocked(FileCache.java:620)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.queryCacheEntry(FileCache.java:378)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.createFile(FileCache.java:275)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.getFromCacheAndCreateIfMissing(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:184)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:146)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:53)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Error:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Error:Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:485)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.parseClass(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:80)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:66)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:40)
Error:  ... 6 more
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder$DexBuilderException: Unable to convert input to dex archive.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.325 secs
Information:34 errors
Information:9 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 1):

`com.github.vbauer:yandex-translate-api:1.2.5` library uses Java 8 and Android supports only Java 7.

Unfortunately you can't use this library in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But not any variants to add this library??:(

Comment: You can use retrofit2 http://square.github.io/retrofit/ library and easily create your own rest-api service @bekha